# How to calculate a percentage of 2 distinctcounts in a crosstab in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a crosstab that looks like this:

[image: Crosstab]

Active MyChart Count and HAR Count are the summarized fields I want the percent of Active MyChart Count.
Example: 
If Active is 86 and HAR is 163 then 86 is what percent of 163? Answer is .52760 times that by 100 and you get 52.76. I would like that to be under column 1 next to HAR Count. So you would see the numbers like this 86   163    52.76%
Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I would use an embedded summary, they cause additional calculations to appear within each cell of the Cross-Tab.

For example, in a report showing regional sales, you could insert a calculation for each region that shows the percentage of total sales for the country.

Then you need to use the formula below, but don't forget to add an IF statement to check for 0 as you cannot divide by zero:

```
IF GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 0) = 0 then 0 else
( GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex ,0 ) / 
GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex ,1 )) * 100
```

This will give you your percentage.